# Jar conflict in Maven and Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, maven, struts2

I'm having some trouble with jar loading. I deployed a Struts2 web application on Tomcat, and it resulted in error:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:....../Tomcat%206.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:....../Tomcat%206.0/webapps/Timesheet/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
2011-03-31 14:33:48,302 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles:748 - Loading action configurations from: struts-default.xml
2011-03-31 14:33:50,592 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles:832 - Loaded action configuration from: struts-default.xml
...
2011-03-31 14:33:50,809 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register:202 - Loaded type:com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.XWorkConverter name:struts impl:com.opensymphony
.xwork2.util.AnnotationXWorkConverter
Mar 31, 2011 2:33:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Mar 31, 2011 2:33:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/Timesheet] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I have excluded all jar-conflicts in `pom.xml`, but it seems to be another `slf4j-log4j` file in Tomcat lib.

Then I tried to remove the slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar in Tomcat/lib and re-run the war again, but still got another error:

```
Mar 31, 2011 2:44:51 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(...\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\Timesheet\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.4.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class:
javax/servlet/Servlet.class
... // Struts file still loaded here, but another Error filterStart: the same as above.
```

Does I miss anything here?

**EDIT:** I have remove the redundant servlet-api included in pom.xml: it is accidentally included by another jar. But after excluding that jar I got the error:

```
Mar 31, 2011 4:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(...\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\Timesheet\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.4.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class:
javax/servlet/Servlet.class
2011-03-31 16:11:20,234 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles:748 - Loading action configurations from: struts-default.xml
2011-03-31 16:11:21,028 DEBUG com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles:832 - Loaded action configuration from: struts-default.xml
```

My servlet-api in my Tomcat has version 2.5; the excluded servlet-api.jar in pom.xml has version 2.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think tomcat comes with slf4j bundled, so removing it from `tomcat/lib` is a proper step.

Then, you should not have `servlet-api-x.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib`, because it bundled with tomcat. Mark it as `<scope>provided</scope>` in the maven pom.

To make sure everything is cleaned-up call `mvn clean`

Comment: I think it maybe part of the cause, but the problem still persists. Would you mind reviewing my updated question?

Comment: @Hoàng Long mvn clean to make sure old jars are not present in target

Comment: actually, "mvn clean" solve my problem even when I don't exclude servlet-api-2.4.jar in pom.xml. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that something is pulling in servlet-api-2.4.jar which is not supposed to be deployed as part of a webapp.  If you have servlet-api as a dependency in your project, ensure it has a scope of *provided*.  This tells maven to use it for compilation but not for packaging.  (see [this Maven FAQ entry](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#scope-provided) and [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)).

However, servlet-api might also be being pulled in because it is referenced transitively from one of your project dependencies.  If this is the case, trying running:

`mvn` [dependency:tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)

to print out a list of transitive dependencies and where they are coming from.  In the output, search for the servlet-api dependency with a non-provided scope.  You can then remove the offender by adding an exclude to its ancestor dependency in your POM.

Comment: @Bozho: You're right, but after I exclude the servlet-api, the problem still persists. I think that if Tomcat provide the jar, I don't need to include it in pom.xml. Is that right?

Comment: @Hoàng Long: You will still need servlet-api for compilation in Maven, otherwise anything referring to the base Servlet/JSP classes (HttpServlet, ServletRequest, etc.) wont be found when compiling.  It still needs to be included, but with 'provided' scope.

Comment: sorry, but I can't find any way to do this. How can I specify a jar as provided, while it's pulled by a transitive dependency?